# How to print, without the Page Setup Dialog?

Tags: actionscript-3, printing, air, dialog, page-setup

I'm trying to print something with Air. Now everything works, but the Page Setup format shows up everytime. What I would like to achieve, is that the standard printer and standard paper size gets selected automatically. So no dialog pops up.

I found 
`var myPrintJob:PrintJob = new PrintJob();
     if (myPrintJob.supportsPageSetupDialog)
     {
         myPrintJob.showPageSetupDialog();
     }`
but this just gives a possibility to actually show it. Is there a way to NOT show it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS059b243ca571213c1e18d17a124d9fca6d8-8000.html The showPageSetupDialog function is optional so you can just not call it. If you want to change the parameters of the print job in the code see the "Changing print settings" section of the link above.
Hope it helps.